# How to make width ratio equal in XML GridView

Tags: android, xml, gridview

I am new to Android programming and XML. So I want to have a table-like GridView which will be 100% width(match_parent) so that the children will have equal width ratio. The GridView will have 4 children which should have a 25% of the GridView width each.

Using HTML to illustrate, I will have something like this in my table `<td width="25% valign="center">`

So here's my XML code

```
<GridView 
    androìd:layout_width="match_parent"
    androìd:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:rowCount="1"
    android:columnCount="4">
    <ImageView
        androìd:layout_width="40dp"
        androìd:layout_height="40dp"
        androìd:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:src="@drawable/p1"/>
    <ImageView
        androìd:layout_width="40dp"
        androìd:layout_height="40dp"
        androìd:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:src="@drawable/p2"/>
    <ImageView
        androìd:layout_width="40dp"
        androìd:layout_height="40dp"
        androìd:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:src="@drawable/p3"/>
    <ImageView
        androìd:layout_width="40dp"
        androìd:layout_height="40dp"
        androìd:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="4"
        android:src="@drawable/p4"/>
</GridView>
```

But this code doesn't make the it look like a table or grid, it just align the images horizontally. Please I need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `constraintLayout` it's very easy :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/image1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/red"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"/>

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/image2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/image1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parentparent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/green"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"/>

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/image3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/image1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/yellow"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"/>

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/image4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/image2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/red"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Then what about the images?

Comment: Now you have four images. just set `android:src="@drawable/yourDrawableName"` for each to load image to it